# When should I put the "dot" while instantiating a module?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In the example, there is an error when I put a dot as shown in "enc_en", is there anything wrong with my implementation?

```
module some_top_module();
....
logic [NOF_PORTS-1:0] wr_en_vec;
logic [NOF_PORTS-1:0] rd_en_vec;
logic enc_en;
encoder #(.IN_W(ADDR_WIDTH)) enc(avalon_aligned_if.slave.ext, .enc_en, .wr_en_vec);
...
endmodule

module encoder #(parameter IN_W = 2)(enc_in, enc_en, enc_out);

function integer expb2 (input [31:0] value);
for (expb2  = 1; value > 0; expb2  = expb2 << 1) begin
value = value -1;
end
endfunction

localparam OUT_W = expb2(IN_W);

input logic [IN_W-1:0] enc_in;
input logic enc_en;
output logic [OUT_W-1:0] enc_out;
 ...
 ...
 endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is illegal.  VCS produces a helpful error:

```
  The two types of module port connections, by ordered list and by name, shall
  not be mixed.
```

Without a *leading* `.`, you  are using ordered port list, and with the leading `.`, you're using port list by name.

```
encoder #(.IN_W(ADDR_WIDTH)) enc(avalon_aligned_if.slave.ext, .enc_en, .wr_en_vec);
//                                 by-order                    by-name
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 23.3.2 *Module instantiation syntax*.